# Why can in-class initializers only use = or {}?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer, curly-braces

[In-class initializers](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init) (C++11 feature) must be enclosed in curly braces or follow a = sign. They may not be specified inside parenthesis.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I am not 100% positive about this, but this might be to prevent a syntax ambiguity.  For example, consider the following class:

```
class BadTimes {
    struct Overloaded;
    int Overloaded;            // Legal, but a very strange idea.

    int confusing(Overloaded); // <-- This line
};
```

What does the indicated line mean?  As written, this is a declaration of a member function named `confusing` that accepts as a parameter an object of type `Overloaded` (whose name isn't specified in the function declaration) and returns an `int`.  If C++11 were to allow initializers to use parentheses, this would be ambiguous, because it could also be a definition of a member of type `int` named `confusing` that is initialized to the value of the data member `Overloaded`.  (This is related to the current issue with the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).)

By requiring curly braces, this ambiguity is removed:

```
class BadTimes {
    struct Overloaded;
    int Overloaded;            // Legal, but a very strange idea.

    int confusing{Overloaded}; // <-- This line
};
```

Now, it's clear that `confusing` is actually an `int` initialized to the value of `Overloaded`, because there's no way to read it as a function declaration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This makes sense to me, but we already have this confusion in a function body for example. Why should it be different here?

Comment: @Rakete111 In a function body, IIRC because of the Most Vexing Parse the statement `int confusing(Overloaded)` would be treated as a function prototype rather than a variable declaration, so I think the behavior is consistent. The use of parentheses for initialization is historical and there new brace-based initializers were in part designed to avoid the ambiguities of older syntax.

Comment: There is no ambiguity, in all your described cases `Overloaded` refers to the `int`, and no vexing parse occurs. This doesn't answer the question IMO