# Why in-class initializer can't use ( )

Tags: c++

Today when I read *C++ Primer* ,it said **in-class initializer** can't use **()** I have searched on Stackoverflow [and find a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329962/why-can-in-class-initializers-only-use-or).And the accepted answer say:the reason might be that there is a ambiguous between **declaration of a member function** and **definition of a member of type**.But I am not complete agree with him.I try the following code:

```
struct Sales_data
{
    int i(5); //this line can't be regard as a function
};
```

But the compiler still complain.Who can tell me why.\
compiler:clang++ version:3-4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is disallowed by the language. The reason is that there would be cases where it couldn't be disambiguated from a function declaration:

```
struct foo
{
  int bar();
};
```

So instead of replicating the whole [*most vexing parse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) fiasco by allowing `()` to work sometimes, it is outright disallowed.

Comment: More about the reasoning behind this decision can be found in [proposal N2756](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm), in `Problem 1` section.