# Error when trying initialize a set in a class

Tags: c++, set, initialization

I define a class named Quote and there is a multiset in it:

```
class Quote

{
public:
    Quote()=default;
    Quote(const std::string& book, double sales_price) :
        bookNo(book), price(sales_price) {}

    std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
private:
    std::string bookNo;
    static bool compare(const std::shared_ptr<Quote> &lhs, const std::shared_ptr<Quote> &rhs)
    {
        return lhs->isbn() < rhs->isbn();
    }
    std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<Quote>, decltype(compare)*>   items(compare);
protected:
    double price = 0.0;
    
};
```

But my IDE(Visual Studio) shows that [function Quote::compare is not a type name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Askme.png)

I usually initialize a set this way out of a class and it works well. Why that happens in a class? Thanks.

Comment: Change `items(compare)` to `items{compare}`

Comment: @ChrisMM It works.Thank you. I just wonder why i cannot use ( ) ?

Comment: @VictorLi [Why can in-class initializers only use = or {}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329962/why-can-in-class-initializers-only-use-or)

Comment: @ChrisMM It really helps me. Thanks a lot!